# How do you create a combination lock in Rec Room?

Tags: rec-room

I'm looking to create a combination lock in Rec Room. Players will search around the room for a numeric code that's 4 digits long. Once they have the code, they can enter it into the circuit somehow to unlock a door. I'm looking for a cheap solution that will work well and will be easy to use. Ideally I'd like for them to see the code they've entered on a sign or text gadget before submitting.

Answer (score 1):

I produced a whole video on the topic of cheap dynamic password systems. Take a look this solves your problem and also shows how to construct a very cheap password checking and generating system and some advice on building a cheap input system.

The basic premise is a circuit that sequentially concatenates the user input and checks if it is equal to the key.

If you don't want to build it the invention featured in the video is called "cheap password".

Comment: Adding the video is a good supplement, but would it be possible to expand in the text portion of the answer? Some screenshots from the RRCS as well as some explanations would make this answer even better.